# Multi-module Maven project and jetty:run

Tags: maven-2, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to split a Maven WAR project into two modules, so that I can build a separate JAR file with command line tools. The result has the following structure:

- `pom.xml` (packaging `pom`, has two modules)
- `project-jar/`

  - `pom.xml` (packaging `jar`)
- `project-war/`

  - `pom.xml` (packaging `war`, depends on `project-jar`)

If I run `mvn` commands from the root, everything works fine. I'd like to keep using `mvn jetty:run`, but for that I need to execute the command in the WAR subproject. If I do that, fails to find the `project-jar` subproject, so it won't run. Even `mvn jetty:run-war` with a completely assembled WAR file in the `target` directory fails, because it first tries to "build" the project. I've only managed to make it work by installing `project-jar` into the local Maven repository, which isn't very nice.

Is there a way to use the Jetty plugin in a multi-module Maven configuration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no magical solution and the only one I know is a bit hacky and rely on the `extraClasspath` element that you can use to declare extra class directories, relatively. Like this (from [JETTY-662](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-662)):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1.v20091125</version>
  <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <webAppConfig>
      <contextPath>/my-context</contextPath>
      <extraClasspath>target/classes;../my-jar-dependency/target/classes</extraClasspath>
    </webAppConfig>
    <scanTargets>
      <scanTarget>../my-jar-dependency/target/classes</scanTarget>
    </scanTargets>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hm, this doesn't actually help me, because it fails with a BUILD error "Failed to resolve artifact." (the sibling JAR project) before the Jetty plugin even gets executed. So it seems I need a general solution for Maven in the first place. :(

Comment: @Lukáš Maven uses the local repository to resolve dependencies so they **must** be installed (i.e. you need to `install` all modules first by running a reactor build on the parent at least once). Then the above will work, even if the installed JARs are "outdated".

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to avoid that. One alternative I found out was setting the jetty plugin on the parent and pointing it to the right war file (and then use jetty:run-war), but I'll probably need to run install anyway to make NetBeans happy.

Comment: can you write how you managed to tell jetty where the modules war file resides?

Answer (score 29):

Create a profile inside the war module (`project-war`).  Within this profile, configure jetty to attach to a lifecycle phase and execute the `run` goal explicitly.  Now when maven runs from the toplevel project with that profile enabled, it will invoke jetty:run and have sister module dependency resolution (as is normal when executing maven commands from the toplevel project).

The example configuration, when placed in the pom.xml of the web module (`project-war`), arranges for jetty:run to execute during the `test` phase.  (You may choose another phase, but make sure it's after `compile`.)

Run from toplevel: `mvn test -Pjetty-run` or `mvn test -DskipTests=true -Pjetty-run`.  This will compile dependencies as required and make them available but invoke jetty:run within the correct module.

```
<profiles>
  ...
  <!-- With this profile, jetty will run during the "test" phase -->
  <profile>
    <id>jetty-run</id>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>7.1.6.v20100715</version>
          <configuration>
            ...
            <webAppSourceDirectory>
              ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}
            </webAppSourceDirectory>
            ...
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>jetty-run</id>
              <phase>test</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
...
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using extraClasspath in jetty configuration works... but for some reason, if dependant jars (from other modules) are outdated some things won't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Add jetty plugin to the root pom and configure a contextHandler pointing to the desired war. This works for me in a project with multiple jar modules and two overlay wars.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.3.0.M2</version>
<configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <contextHandlers>
            <contextHandler
                implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext">
                <war>${project.basedir}/project-war/target/project-war-${project.version}.war</war>
                <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            </contextHandler>
        </contextHandlers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#running-more-than-one-webapp

Answer (score 0):

I know you're asking for plugin configuration, but you could just define the project in the maven command:

```
$ mvn jetty:run --projects project-war
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `jetty:run`](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#jetty-run-goal) notes that

> As of Jetty 9.4.7, when using jetty:run in a multi-module build, it is no longer necessary to build each of the modules that form dependencies of the webapp first. Thus, if your webapp depends on other modules in your project and they are present in the reactor at the same time, jetty will use their compiled classes rather than their jar files from your local maven repository.

Thus, add the `jetty-maven-plugin` to the Maven root project and run `mvn jetty:run`