# Using maven jetty plugin in multi-module project under Eclipse

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, maven-jetty-plugin

I am working on a simple multi module maven project under Eclipse using m2eclipse with maven 3 and jetty plugin version 7. One of my module is a jar and the other module is a war which has a dependency on the jar.

Even though the workspace dependency resolution is enabled, the call to mvn jetty:run fails if I don't run mvn install before.

Having read about workspace dependency, I am not sure why a call to mvn install is required. I would like to be able to run the jetty plugin without installing the artifacts to my local repository. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636493/multi-module-maven-project-and-jettyrun

Comment: My question is specifically about using the Jetty maven plugin from Eclipse with m2Eclipse. The link that you provide is useful but does not quite answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is an integration module between *m2eclipse* and the [*WTP* (Web Tool Platform)](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).

WTP allow starting Jetty/Tomcat/... from Eclipse, debugging inside Eclipse, redeploy on change,...

Here is it: [m2eclipse Extras](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html)