# Maven jetty plugin - automatic reload using a multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, maven-module

I am developing a Java web application, using a multi-module maven project. The project setup is the following:

- `pom.xml` Main maven project, that includes the following modules:

  - `persistence:` Entity classes and DAOs
  - `business:` Service definition and implementation
  - `webapp:` Apache wicket web application

The dependency hierarchy is the following: `webapp` depends on `business`, which depends on `persistence`.

I am also using the [Jetty Maven Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) to run the web application locally using `mvn -pl webapp jetty:run` inside the directory with the main `pom.xml`. When developing the application, When making code changes, I want the jetty server to restart and reload the modified code files automatically. This works fine when I am modifying files inside the `webapp` module, but **does not work** when I am modifying a file inside another module, such `persistence` or `business`.

The Maven Jetty Plugin is configured inside `webapp/pom.xml` as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
    <configuration>
        <reload>automatic</reload>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webApp>
            <extraClasspath>../business/target/classes/;../persistence/target/classes/</extraClasspath>
        </webApp>
        <scanTargets>
            <scanTarget>../business/target/classes</scanTarget>
            <scanTarget>../persistence/target/classes</scanTarget>
        </scanTargets>
</plugin>
```

I followed the instructions of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637829/2623126). The `<scanTarget>` tags work fine, since jetty gets restarted when I modify a file inside `business` or `persistence`. However, the `<extraClasspath>` does not work since the modified files are not loaded by jetty. The linked answer uses the `<webAppConfig>` tag. However, I am using the `<webApp>` tag as specified in the [documentation of the plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-your-webapp) (I also tried the old `<webAppConfig>` tag, which lead to the same results).

**My question is:** How to configure the Jetty Maven Plugin for a multi-module project, such that it reloads modified files from other modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using trial and error, I found a solution. The problem is that jetty is executed using from the parent pom using

```
mvn -pl webapp jetty:run
```

The command is called from the directory of the main pom, thus jetty cannot resolve the relative paths inside the `extraClasspath` correctly. When executing the `jetty:run` goal inside the `webapp` directory, all modified classes are loaded correctly.

---

I assume the `scanTargets` are working correctly even when using `mvn -pl webapp jetty:run`, because the relative paths get resolved during the execution of the plugin (with the correct working directory). Jetty outputs the scan targets on startup:

```
[INFO] Added extra scan target:C:\PathToProject\business\target\classes
[INFO] Added extra scan target:C:\PathToProject\persistence\target\classes
```

However, the `<extraClasspath>`property is part of the `<webApp>` property, which is an instance of the [org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html) class. I assume that this instance is passed to jetty directly and that the [extraClasspath](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#getExtraClasspath()) property is accessed by jetty when it is already started.

Comment: Do you have any problem with the PermGen space using this configuration?

Comment: @Skizzo I've had some problems that jetty ran out of memory, but I fixed them by creating a environment variable called `MAVEN_OPTS` with value `-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18674094/2623126 for details)

Answer (score 5):

To force the reload anytime a submodule is changed you can use the following options

1 - Static module names and scan targets

You can define as scan targets the target directory for each module

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>${jetty.scanInterval}</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <scanTargets>
            <scanTarget>module-name/target/classes</scanTarget>
            <scanTarget>module-name2/target/classes</scanTarget>
        </scanTargets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

2 - Dinamic module names and scan targets (recommended)
This uses RegEx to find the compilation target for other modules, on the following example, we are reloading the application everytime a class is compiled on any module

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>${jetty.scanInterval}</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <scanTargetPatterns>
            <scanTargetPattern>
                <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/target/classes/**/*.class</include>
                </includes>
            </scanTargetPattern>
        </scanTargetPatterns>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following configuration works for me

```
    <!-- To launch embded jetty server -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.2.v20110526</version>


    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webAppConfig>
            <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
            <extraClasspath>target/classes;../services/target/classes;../util/target/classes</extraClasspath>
        </webAppConfig>
        <scanTargets>
            <scanTarget>target/classes</scanTarget>
            <scanTarget>../services/target/classes</scanTarget>
            <scanTarget>../util/target/classes</scanTarget>
        </scanTargets>
    </configuration>

</plugin>
```

Comment: I tried the exactly same configuration (i.e. version of the jetty plugin) and it did not work. However, because I new this configuration did work for you, I tried calling `mvn jetty:run` inside the `webapp` directory (see my answer). +1 and thanks for helping me find a solution :)